# view files outside the resources dir in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have a view,in which I would like to store it outside the current `resources/views`. 
Currently we access it like so

```
public function sideBarItems(){
     return view('ApplicationCreator.sideBarItems.blade.php');
}
```

but what if I want to access the view from outside `resources/views`? If my folder tree looks like this.

```
+newFolder
    -foo.blade.php

+resouces
   -views
       -ApplicationCreator
           -sideBarItems.blade.php
```

how should I access the `foo.blade.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the view config file (config/view.php).
Add your directory in the 'paths' array, as follows:

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
    realpath(base_path('newFolder')),
],
```

Comment: added,but it is still not able to find it.

Comment: I use laravel 5.4 and I can confirm that "return view('foo')" load correctly the view newFolder/foo.blade.php if you follow the code above. Plz try to use all lowercase names for folder and view.